# Convert String column to Date in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to write a create statement for creating data source in SSRS. My Create Statement is as follows :-

```
Select TOP(cast(1000 as integer)) Name,
TName,
IName,
IType,
AvgPercent,
FCount,
PCount,
AvgInPages,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RunDate,103) AS  RunDate,
CONVERT(TIME(0), RunTime) AS RTime
 from Index
where RunDateBetween @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Currently I have done it like this `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RunDate,103) AS  RDate,` but between clause is not working. Between Clause only gives me record for start date and nothing after that. So I want to convert varchar to date I tried using this after searching on web `CONVERT(Date,RunDate,103) AS  RunDate` but that gives me date as well as time whereas I just need date in that column. After lot of searching I am not able to find any concerete solution.Please help me.

Comment: Your where clause should be `where RunDate Between @StartDate and @EndDate` , `RDate` column is not available for your where clause. Also make sure that you SSRS parameters are of `Date`  data type

Comment: First, you can't use an alias from the SELECT clause in the WHERE clause, see [Logical Query Processing](http://www.nickyvv.com/2013/02/logical-query-processing.html). And what data type is your RunDate column?

Comment: @NickyvV I have changed name of that column while posting this and now i have edited the code naming it as RunDate...My query is getting executed..DataType is varchar(10)

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
SELECT TOP 1000 NAME
    ,TName
    ,IName
    ,IType
    ,AvgPercent
    ,FCount
    ,PCount
    ,AvgInPages
    ,CAST(RunDate AS DATE) AS RDate
    ,CONVERT(TIME(0), RunTime) AS RTime
FROM INDEX
WHERE CAST(RunDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate
        AND @EndDate
```

Comment: Glad to help you. Please accept it if it was useful.